# Accessing Grunt Current Task from Another Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Let's say I have one task, `myCustomTask` that gets called by another task, `quick`.

```
grunt.registerTask('myCustomTask', function(){
    if(this.nameArgs === 'quick'){
        console.log('ignoring task...');
        return;
    }else{
        grunt.task.run('my-custom-task');
    }
});
```

I would like `myCustomTask` to be ignored by `grunt quick`, **without** removing it from the `quick` task.

```
grunt.registerTask('quick', [
    'task1',
    'task2',
    'myCustomTask'
]);
```

I was hoping `this.nameArgs === 'quick'` would trigger when the task is being ran as `grunt quick` but it skips that and reaches the else block. In other words, the first condition is only met when we use `this.nameArgs === 'myCustomTask'`

How can I target whichever task, is currently calling our custom task so I can tell it to ignore it?

Comment: why do you want to keep 'myCustomTask' in the list if you don't want to run it?

Comment: Because if I have a target `middleman`, that calls `myCustomTask` and a bunch of other directives. `middleman` and all it's directives get called by `quick`, `build` and `dist`... `myCustomTask` is quite heavy and not ideal for `quick` so I'd like it to be ignored by this target only.

Comment: if you take `myCustomTask` off from the `quick` list, it will still be called by `middleman`, but not by `quick` - seems to be what you want. So why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Dynamic alias tasks](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks)?

I think you can do the following:

```
grunt.registerTask('myCustomTask', function(mode) {
    if (mode == 'quick') {
        console.log('ignoring task...');
        return;
    }
    grunt.task.run('my-custom-task');
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to exclude task execution if some task had been ran then you can do the following:

```
var taskSettings = {};

grunt.registerTask('task1', function() {
    console.log('task 1');
});
grunt.registerTask('task2', function() {
    if ('quick' == taskSettings.origin) {
        console.log('skip task 2');
    } else {
        console.log('task 2');
    }
});
grunt.registerTask('quick', function () {
    taskSettings.origin = this.name;
    grunt.task.run('task1', 'task2');
});
```

But as for me it looks strange and I would suggest splitting logic among task's targets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: Hi, I've updated solution according to your requirements and it works for me.

Comment: You my friend are an absolute genius. Works great